# Display number of records in a page in datatables

Tags: datatables, records

I need to show the Display number of records in a page by using datatables plugin.
I have included the following js files:

```
js/jquery.dataTables.js
js/ColVis.js
js/ColumnFilterWidgets.js
js/extras/TableTools/media/js/ZeroClipboard.js
js/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js
js/extras/TableTools/media/js/TableTools.js
```

and code is like:

```
oTable = $('#data-table').dataTable( {
         "sDom": 'CT<"clear">firtlip',
        "oTableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": basePath+"/js/extras/TableTools/media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
            "aButtons": [ {"sExtends": "csv","sFileName" : curpath+".csv","sButtonText": "Save to CSV","mColumns": "visible"} ]
        },
       "aaSorting": [[0, "desc"]],
       "bAutoWidth":false,
       "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
       "iDisplayLength": 10,
       'sPaginationType': 'full_numbers'
    } );
```

But the select box for for selecting the number of records is not displaying.
Please guide me where is the issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks problem has been resolved. The div class had been hide in css.

Comment: When you should close the question, or answer it yourself and accept the answer (recommended). The question should not stay open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change your css then automatically solve the issue. Just change "display:none" to "display:block" for data-table_length class in css.